# Question on a proof involving linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I've encountered the following proof, but I'm stuck at the last step.

Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}^s$ be a vector space. Let $p(x): X \to \mathbb{R}$ be a linear transformation such that $p(x)$ must be positive if every element of $x \in X$ is positive. Create

$$M = \{ (-p(x), x); x \in X \}$$

Then $M$ is a vector space given the linearity of $p(x)$. In fact, $M$ cannot consist entirely of positive elements, so $M$ is a hyperplane that only intersects the positive orthant of $\mathbb{R}_+^{s+1}$ at the point $0$.

I understand everything above, but at the end, it says:

We can then create a linear function $F : \mathbb{R}^{s+1} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $F(-p,x) = 0$ for $(-p,x) \in M$, and $F(-p,x) > 0$ for $(-p,x) \in \mathbb{R}_+^{s+1}$ except the origin.

I don't understand how this follows. How can you be sure that you can create such a function? Is there a theorem that I'm missing?

Comment: Any linear transformation is uniquely defined by what it does on a basis. So take a basis of $M$ and define $F$ to be zero on any element of said basis. Can you finish from here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is such a theorem, but it's the function that canonically arises given those conditions. Define your function for $x\in\mathbb{R}^s,y\in\mathbb{R}$ as follows:
$$
F(y,x) = y + p(x)
$$

First of all for $(-p(x),x)\in M$ we get $F(-p(x),x) = -p(x) + p(x) = 0$, so the first condition is fulfilled. Now let's take a vector $(y,x)$ from the positive orthant $\mathbb{R}^{s+1}_+$. But as $x> 0$ we know - given the definition of $p$ - that $p(x) > 0$ as well. With $y> 0$ we get $F(y,x) = y + p(x) > 0$ and thus $F$ does fulfill the given condition

Comment: How is this fact "$M$ is a hyperplane that only intersects the positive orthant of $\mathbb{R}^{s+1}_+$ at the point 0" used?

Comment: This is indirectly used by the fact that points $(-p,x)$ are elements of $M$ if $-p(x)=-p$. But either every element of $x$ is positive, then $p$ is positive and $-p$ negative or at least one element of $x$ is negative. This proves that $M$ only intersects with the positive orthant in $0$. This shows that this property can be immediately derived by the definition of $p$ - and this property of $p$ is used in may proof